# Making two same rows appear as one 'big' row with datagridview

Tags: vb.net

Sometimes i have two exactly rows populating my datagridview. How can i make it so instead of showing two rows, it would render just one big row? Like this:>

From

```
| column1 || column2 || column3 || column4 |
| column1 || column2 || column3 || column4 |
```

To

```
|         ||         ||         ||         |
| column1 || column2 || column3 || column4 |
|         ||         ||         ||         |
```

Don't mind my 'drawing' skills.

Comment: You're looking for something like `ColumnSpan` and/or `RowSpan` which i don't think is an out of the box feature. Try google it.

Comment: You could Google 'Datagridview Merge Cells' etc 
 - I have a feeling I used something based on this many moons ago:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b659cbd-7d29-4da4-8b38-5d427c3762e2/how-can-i-merge-two-cells-of-datagridview-control-in-vbnet?forum=vbinterop

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that "automatically" using `DataGridView`. There's no built-in option for that. You will have to code a little bit. You could try a couple of options:

1. Loop your rows and if you find 2 equal rows, remove one row and set the height of the other to its double. It would be better to do this before binding your data to the DataGridView.DataSource.
2. Use a modified control like [DataGridVewTextBoxCell with Span Behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour) to span your rows.